# Function to find roots using Newtons Method with jacobian and transpose

Tags: matlab, matrix, newtons-method

Given f=[f1,f2]^t
and the jacobian matrix for it

How can i make a function using Newtons method that takes initial guess of x1,x2 with a tolerance of E and a max iterations of k to find the roots?

Comment: Oh, come on. Make an effort. Do you intend to post every homework problem here for someone else to do for you? Will we get the grade or you?

Answer (score 0):

roots are places where f1 and f2 are both zeros. so you can use a cost function of the form `f1^2 + f2^2`, and use fmincond/fminunc/fminsearch to find answers